# Find a limit of $\ln(u_n)/2^n$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $u_0 \in \mathbb{N}^{*}$ and $(u_n)$ such that $u_{n+1}=1+u_n^2$.

I've shown that the sequence $\displaystyle \left(\frac{\ln\left(u_n\right)}{2^n}\right)$ converges and I wonder if it possible to find its limit $\ell$

For example, if $u_0=1$ then $\ell \approx 0.40735$, if $u_0=15$ then $\ell \approx  2.7103$.

Comment: A very good question (+1).

Comment: $2*\ln($ [A076949](http://oeis.org/A076949) $)$ is what it converges to for $u_0 = 1$. In the OEIS, there is no closed form for this.

Answer (score 1):

*This is not an answer.*

With the $2^n$ in denominator, the limit is obtained quite fast.

Let $u_0=10^k$ and computing we get
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
k & \ell_k \\
 0 & 0.407354523 \\
 1 & 2.307584766 \\
 2 & 4.605220186 \\
 3 & 6.907755779 \\
 4 & 9.210340377 \\
 5 & 11.51292547 \\
 6 & 13.81551056 \\
 7 & 16.11809565 \\
 8 & 18.42068074 \\
 9 & 20.72326584
\end{array}
\right)$$ and, as you can see, $\ell_k \sim k \log(10)$